# How can I write from multiple writers in golang?

Tags: go, io, writer

The idea is to create a function that will write to several writers and do a return so that:

- write the []byte slice to all writers
- return n  bytes written by each writer with index position corresponding to the index position of the writer.
  -if slice is empty return  ([]int{})
  ... etc

Error function:

```
type Errors []error


func (m Errors) Error() string {
    count := 0
    for t := 0; t < len(m); t++ {
        if m[t] != nil {
            count += 1

        }
    }
    errindex := 0
    for t := 0; t < len(m); t++ {
        if m[t] != nil {
            errindex = t
            break
        }
    }

    if count == 0 {
        return fmt.Sprintf("(0 errors)")
    } else {
        if count == 1 {
            return fmt.Sprintf("%v", m[errindex])
        } else if count == 2 {
            return fmt.Sprintf("%v (and 1 other error)", m[errindex])
        } else {
            return fmt.Sprintf("%v (and %d other errors)", m[errindex], count-1)

        }

    }
}
```

My new code:

```
func WriteTo(b []byte, writers ...io.Writer) (n []int, errs errors.Errors) {
    if len(writers) == 0 {
        return []int{}, nil
    }
    for i := 0; i < len(writers); i++ {
        num, err := writers[i].Write(b) // write bytes to a current writer
        n = append(n, num)              // add bytes written by current write
        if err!=nil{
            switch err{
            case io.ErrShortWrite:
                errs = append(errs, err)
            default:
                errs = append(errs, err)
            }
        }
    }
    return n, errs
}
```

I try to fix it but some tests don't pass. Can't really see the problem. Instead of returning when count == 1, returns when count == 0 and when count == 2, return as for count == 0

```
    []error{nil, io.ErrShortWrite, nil},

    []error{nil, io.ErrShortWrite, io.ErrShortWrite},
```

Comment: You may use MultiWriter (https://pkg.go.dev/io#MultiWriter )

Comment: I found some solution but not all test successed.

Comment: if err is short write you are appending it twice to the out slice.

Comment: @mh-cbon Can you explain more? even if i change `if err == io.ErrShortWrite {
   errs = append(errs, err)
  } else if err != nil {
   errs = append(errs, err)
  }`  it return same failure

Comment: You can't be vaguer than that TBH; can you show us the tests that are failing? What's the stack trace? What's expected and what's produced?

Answer (score 4):

You may use [`io.MultiWriter()`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#MultiWriter) which takes arbitrary number of [`io.Writer`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Writer)s and returns a single `io.Writer`, which duplicates writes to all provided writers.

For example:

```
buf1 := &bytes.Buffer{}
buf2 := &bytes.Buffer{}

w := io.MultiWriter(buf1, buf2)

if _, err := w.Write([]byte("Hello")); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Println("Buf1:", buf1.String())
fmt.Println("Buf2:", buf2.String())
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/b_18b1UALZY)):

```
Buf1: Hello
Buf2: Hello
```

Comment: Yes, but what if the number of writers are unknown? And io.MultiWriter() function can only return a single error, and it is not
possible to figure out which of the original writers caused the error. And in my case I want to know.

Comment: regarding `return n bytes written by each writer with index position corresponding to the index position of the writer. -if slice is empty return ([]int{}) ... etc` it could be mentioned  that if one of the writer does not write the same amount as others, some errors will be returned.

Comment: I created an Error interface with Err function that : takes a slice of errors : func (m Errors) Error() string    : and return either 0 errors if none,, error 1, err1 and tells that there are x errors